# Default toolbars in SSMS 2012 (SQL Server Management Studio) at startup

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssms, ssms-2012

I am running Windows 7 and Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio 2012 (Version build 11.0.5058.0).

I know that the available toolbars can be customized, but every time I close SSMS and reopen, it resets the default toolbar sets that I had showing and their arrangement.

Is there a way to set a default set of toolbars and their arrangement that display when I start the program?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with defaults in SQL server. I followed the steps below

1. Within Management SQL Server Management Studio, select “Window” from the top menu bar.
2. Select “Reset Window Layout”.
3. Answer “Yes” to the question confirming the layout reset.

Answer (score -1):

I'm able to customize the toolbars and then exit out and come back in with the changes showing.

There are a number of great blogs on how to customize the toolbars.  Here's one that I used:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/customize-menu-and-toolbar-in-sql-server-2012/

Sorry I couldn't help more!

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. Unfortunately this site only tells me how to customize the toolbars, it does not cover how to set defaults at startup.